# CSS3 flip doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, css-transforms

I have a div flipping when clicking on a button, to show another div.

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front"><h1>FRONT</h1></div>
        <div class="back"><h1>BACK</h1></div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="flipper-btn">Flip it!</button>
```

It is working beautiful in chrome but (of course) not in IE. It just shows the backside of the .front div, and not the .back div. I have searched for an answer, and found that a few others had problems with the same thing, but I haven't been able to get mine to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/0sypya5h/3/

Hope that somebody can help...

Comment: `transform` works in IE9+ http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3%20Transforms

Comment: what is your IE version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the [lack of support for `preserve-3d`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) in Internet Explorer 11. We recently shipped support in http://remote.modern.ie (supported on Android, OS X, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone).

You can expect this to land in an upcoming stable build. Until native support ships you may find more success animating both of the elements independently rather than attempting to so in a compounding fashion:

```css
.flipped .front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipped .back {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/wv3rymoe/

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga Try `-ms-transform` instead of `transform`.

Comment: not working. from what I know -ms-transform doesn't exist anymore. It was supported in some versions of IE but removed in the latest versions of ie11 and currently no up to date ie browser supports it.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga Looks like a bug in IE 11. Removing the `backface-visibility` causes it to render, but breaks the intended effect.

Comment: yeah, I think this used to work for ie11 but not working in the latest versions. and now of course microsoft stopped improving the browser.